# Find even numbers upto n in kdb?

Tags: kdb

Can you please help to write optimized function to find even numbers upto n without mod and scanning each element in upto n number.

I didn't understand below kdb code to find even number, please explain me below function.

```
is x even

x:1 2 3 4 5

~x!2

0 1 0 1 0
```

how do I convert kdb code into q function?

I found an example on google, however do not want this solution. I found better solution in kdb and not able to convert kdb code to Q.

```
L:til 100
{ $[0~(x mod 2);-1 string[x]," is even"; -1 string[x]," is not"]} each L;
```

Comment: It believe your example is written in k9 which is not supported by kdb by kx. `~x!2` can be written in q like this: `not x mod 2` so it does use mod. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: @IgorKorkhov I found above logic in kdb idioms. It looks interesting for me to learn kdb idioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t fully understand your question. But you could try something like:

```
//Function to generate even numbers up to N excluding 0
/x div 2 reduces the list length by half that kdb has to generate using til
/i.e. it does not have to generate the full list up to N then filter the even numbers, hence optimized
{2*1+til x div 2}
//Function to filter even numbers from list input
/x mod 2 is a test to check if number is odd
{x where not x mod 2}
```

Comment: Hi Maurice Lim,    You have answered to my question. It's not required full list of numbers so that we can save memory and no need to do mod operation to find even number. 3 5 7 ... are not even numbers and it can skip mod operation to save time.  Thank you